# Display has not succeeded; LiquidCrystal_I2C, 20x4 display, 8 bit, I2C backpack

Tags: arduino

I am struggling with an Arduino device that I cannot find any similar examples.

I have a 20x4 display, and a I2C backpack, with four wires. I've put ground and power where they should be, as well as Data and Clock to A4 and A5 respectively.

I have tried to get the display to work by finding similar code. Below, was an attempt that did not involve an error code, but still no display result.

I constructed it by using the documentation that came with the device, a table that shows for instance Symbol RS corresponding with Pin 4. And the Default setting Address is `0x27`

Here is an attempted code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#define I2C_ADDR    0x27
#define En_pin      2
#define Rw_pin      5
#define Rs_pin      4
#define D4_pin      0
#define D5_pin      1
#define D6_pin      6
#define D7_pin      7
#define BACKLIGHT_PIN   3

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(I2C_ADDR, En_pin, Rw_pin, Rs_pin,
                      D4_pin, D5_pin, D6_pin, D7_pin);

void setup() {
    lcd.begin (20, 4);

    // Switch on the backlight
    lcd.setBacklightPin(BACKLIGHT_PIN, POSITIVE);
    lcd.setBacklight(LOW);

    // Position cursor and write some text
    lcd.home();
    lcd.print("Hello World");
}

void loop() {

}
```

By the way, I am not sure how to navigate whether I should be choosing another library for LiquidCrystal, or LiquidCrystal_I2C. There seemed to be newer versions than those on the ArduinoPlayground.

Also, some examples write `lcd(0, 20, 4)`, not sure about that either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an I2C backpack, such as the PCF8574, you should initialise your LCD using the I2C constructor, not the parallel one.

`LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(I2C_ADDR, 20, 4);`